# JavaFX Boolean Binding for an value ContextMenuItem

Tags: java, javafx

I want to bind a MenuItem of my contextMenu to an specific value of the selectedValue of the tableView.
Like you can see in the picture: if status is "anwesend" what is specified with an int = 2 in the Controller, then the option should be disabled.

I thought about this here, but it throws a NullPointer because the selection is empty:

```
contextMenuItemUnentschuldigt.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> !loggedIn || tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getExcused() == 2));
```

[image]

But how to check first if it's not empty and then check that it's not that specific value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer:

```
contextMenuItemUnentschuldigt.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().isEmpty() || tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getExcused() == 2, tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()));
```